# How to expand a UITableView inside a StackView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uistackview

I have programatically created a Stackview along with a UITableView inside it.

```
func setupStack() {
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.spacing = 8
}

func fillStackView() {
yearTable.isHidden = true
        yearTable.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        allViews.append(yearTable) // adding the view to an array of views
// other views also created and added to stack

}
```

My problem is that when I fade in the tableView, it takes up as much space as the other views in the table which all have a height of 40. The tableView has a height of 150 but it never expands to that height. How do I get it to expand?

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` does not have an intrinsic height/width so when placed in a `UIStackView` without any height/width information, it will be provided a default size. i.e. if your tallest view in the stack is 60 in height, then the `tableView` will also be 60.

You could alter this by giving `yearTable` a height constraint before adding it to the `UIStackView`, like so:

```
func fillStackView() {
    //...
    yearTable.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    yearTable.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true

    allViews.append(yearTable)
    //...
}
```

But do note that if you do this then because of `stackView.distribution = .fillEqually`, all your other views in the `UIStackView` will also become 150.

---

#### (EXTRA) Playground Example:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    stackView.spacing = 8

    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(stackView)

    stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true

    return stackView
  }()

  let datasource = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    appendLabel(text: "Hello, World!", color: .lightGray)
    appendLabel(text: "Lorem\nipsum\ndolor\nsit", color: .gray)
    appendTableView()
  }

  func appendLabel(text: String, color: UIColor) {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.backgroundColor = color
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.text = text
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
  }

  func appendTableView() {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    tableView.dataSource = self

    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true

    stackView.addArrangedSubview(tableView)
  }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return datasource.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    let item = datasource[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(item)
    return cell
  }
}

let vc = ViewController()
vc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480)
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(vc.view)
```

- Comment `tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true` to see the difference